# Why doesn't pressing ok in messagebox error message take you back to form1 instead of form2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an IF statement that validates an email. If its true, form2 closes and returns email address to form1. But if its false, it has a error message pop up and say 'enter correct email' and return to form2 which it doesn't. It just closes form2 automatically and goes back to form1.

Form1

```
        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkNewMember.Checked)
        {
            Email form = new Email();
            form.ShowDialog();
            lblDisplay.Text = form.validEmail;
        }
    }
```

Form2

```
public partial class Email : Form
{
    public string validEmail;
    public Email()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void getEmail()
    {
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (isEmail)
        {
            validEmail = email;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address.", "Invalid Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getEmail();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your code...

Comment: pls show us code what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at your code:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getEmail();
    this.Close();
}
```

Regardless of what `getEmail()` does, you will call `this.Close()` after clicking the submit button - whether the email is valid or not. As the simplest fix, try moving `this.Close()` into your `getEmail()` method so that you only call it when the email is valid, like so:

```
    if (isEmail)
    {
        validEmail = email;
        this.Close();
    }
    else 
    {
        // ... now the messagebox will display but the form *won't* be closed
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your form has the property `AcceptButton` set to your `Submit` button.

In this scenario the WinForms engine closes the form automatically when you press the Submit button and sets the property DialogResult of your form2 to the same DialogResult property set on the Submit button.

If you want to stop the Winforms engine to automatically close your form in case a validation fails then you need to manually set the form DialogResult property to `DialogResult.None`

```
....

public bool getEmail()
{
    string email = txtEmail.Text;
    bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (isEmail)
    {
        validEmail = email;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address.", "Invalid Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return false;
    }
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!getEmail())
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

Notice that you don't need to call explicitly the Close method of the form. You could let the WinForm engine handle it if you set the AcceptButton and the CancelButton on the form property designer.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with that but that code gives me an error of Error Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'

Comment: The example above that calls ValidateEMail expects it to return a boolean TRUE/FALSE if the validation succeed or not. You should adapt this example to your scenario. The important thing is. If the validation fails you need to set the form DialogResult property to None to stop the closing process.

Comment: Well, no, it's probably not that complicated. The OP is calling `this.Close` explicitly.

Comment: @DanPuzey yes I missed that, however I leave the question here because I think that this is the correct way to work with modal dialogs.

Comment: I do agree that `DialogResult` is useful. From the standpoint of this question, it's a valid requirement to not allow the form to be submitted (i.e. closed with the Submit button) in the case of invalid input. Given that requirement, your `DialogResult` assignment is always going to be redundant - so while I agree in principle, I don't think it was relevant here.